# How to use wrapper feature selection algorithms in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, feature-selection

I have several algorithms: rpart, kNN, logistic regression, randomForest, Naive Bayes, and SVM. I'd like to use forward/backward and genetic algorithm selection for finding the best subset of features to use for the particular algorithms.

How can I implement wrapper type forward/backward and genetic selection of features in R?

Comment: Wrappers are used in data preprosessing, giving out the best List of Predictors

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing wrappers at the moment so I'll give you a few Pacckage names in R. What is a [wrapper](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/)? [image]

Now to the Methods:
MASS Package: **Choose a model by AIC in a Stepwise Algorithm**

`stepAIC(model, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)
stepAIC(model, direction = "backward", trace = FALSE)
stepAIC(model, direction = "forward", trace = FALSE)`

Carte Package: **Backwards Feature Selection**

```
control <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs, method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, verbose = TRUE)
rfe_results <- rfe(x, y, sizes = c(1:10), rfeControl = control)
```

or **Supervised feature selection using genetic algorithms**

```
gafs_results <- gafs(x, y, gafsControl = control)
```

or **Simulated annealing feature selection**

```
safs_results <-  safs(x, y, iters = 10, safsControl = control)
```

hope i could give you a good overview. There are a lot more Methods out there...

Answer (score 0):

The `caret` package in R has extensive functionality for doing this, and it would be very easy to switch amongst the algorithms you mentioned.

There is also a lot of documentation on their site:

- http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html for a general overview of feature selection in caret
- http://topepo.github.io/caret/rfe.html to implement recursive feature elimination
- http://topepo.github.io/caret/GA.html for genetic algorithms.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Achekroud, I did look at these but couldn't see how to implement in a wrapper. They appear to do feature selection prior to running the algorithm? Do you know of any example code on how to implement please?

Comment: These are wrapper methods... here is an example explained in a blog post: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/12/caret-genetic.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for forward feature selection

```
selectFeature <- function(train, test, cls.train, cls.test, features) {
  ## identify a feature to be selected
  current.best.accuracy <- -Inf #nagtive infinity
  selected.i <- NULL
  for(i in 1:ncol(train)) {
    current.f <- colnames(train)[i]
    if(!current.f %in% features) {
      model <- knn(train=train[,c(features, current.f)],      test=test[,c(features, current.f)], cl=cls.train, k=3)
      test.acc <- sum(model == cls.test) / length(cls.test)

      if(test.acc > current.best.accuracy) {
        current.best.accuracy <- test.acc
        selected.i <- colnames(train)[i]
      }
    }
  }
  return(selected.i)
}


##
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .6)[[1]]
allFeatures <- colnames(Sonar)[-61]
train <- Sonar[ inTrain,-61]
test  <- Sonar[-inTrain,-61]
cls.train <- Sonar$Class[inTrain]
cls.test <- Sonar$Class[-inTrain]

# use correlation to determine the first feature
cls.train.numeric <- rep(c(0, 1), c(sum(cls.train == "R"),   sum(cls.train == "M")))
features <- c()
current.best.cor <- 0
for(i in 1:ncol(train[,-61])) {
  if(current.best.cor < abs(cor(train[,i], cls.train.numeric))) {
    current.best.cor <- abs(cor(train[,i], cls.train.numeric))
    features <- colnames(train)[i]
  }
}
print(features)

# select the 2 to 10 best features using knn as a wrapper classifier
for (j in 2:10) {
  selected.i <- selectFeature(train, test, cls.train, cls.test, features)
  print(selected.i)

  # add the best feature from current run
  features <- c(features, selected.i)
}
```