# R: Feature Selection with Cross Validation using Caret on Logistic Regression

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation, feature-extraction

I am currently learning how to implement logistical Regression in R

I have taken a data set and split it into a training and test set and wish to implement `forward selection`, `backward selection` and `best subset selection` using cross validation to select the best features.
I am using `caret` to implement `cross-validation` on the training data set and then testing the predictions on the test data.

I have seen the `rfe` control in caret and had also had a look at the documentation on the `caret` [website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-overview.html) as well as following the links on the question [How to use wrapper feature selection with algorithms in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746575/how-to-use-wrapper-feature-selection-with-algorithms-in-r). It isn't apparent to me how to change the type of feature selection as it seems to default to backward selection. Can anyone help me with my workflow. Below is a reproducible example

```
library("caret")

# Create an Example Dataset from German Credit Card Dataset
mydf <- GermanCredit

# Create Train and Test Sets 80/20 split
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydf$Class, p = .8, 
                              list = FALSE, 
                              times = 1)

train <- mydf[ trainIndex,]
test  <- mydf[-trainIndex,]


ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                 number = 10, 
                 savePredictions = TRUE)

mod_fit <- train(Class~., data=train, 
             method="glm", 
             family="binomial",
             trControl = ctrl, 
             tuneLength = 5)


# Check out Variable Importance
varImp(mod_fit)
summary(mod_fit)

# Test the new model on new and unseen Data for reproducibility
pred = predict(mod_fit, newdata=test)
accuracy <- table(pred, test$Class)
sum(diag(accuracy))/sum(accuracy)
```

Comment: Google search points to this https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-March/305508.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call it in mod_fit. When it comes to backward stepwise the code below is sufficient

```
trControl <- trainControl(method="cv",
                          number = 5,
                          savePredictions = T,
                          classProbs = T,
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

caret_model <- train(Class~.,
                     train,
                     method="glmStepAIC", # This method fits best model stepwise.
                     family="binomial",
                     direction="backward", # Direction
                     trControl=trControl)
```

Note that in trControl

```
method= "cv", # No need to call repeated here, the number defined afterward defines the k-fold.
classProbs = T,
summaryFunction = twoClassSummary # Gives back ROC, sensitivity and specifity of the chosen model.
```